# Removing negative pixels values as No data using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst

I am trying to remove minus pixel values as a No data using ArcPy.

I have written a function in a code, but the function not working properly.

```
outRaster = Con(IsNull (localRaster) >0 , localRaster)
```

Comment: In what precise way is "the function not working properly"?

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting NoData values by using `IsNull` and therefore setting NoData values to NoData

Instead select negative values and use `SetNull` to set them to NoData.

E.g:

```
outRaster = SetNull(localRaster < 0 , localRaster)
```

Or to fix your original expression:

```
outRaster = Con( localRaster >= 0 , localRaster)
```